# Auto Login using j_security_check in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, smartgwt, j-security-check

i am new to smartGWT . i want to create auto login using j_security_check in tomcat. currently i am simple login done using j_security check, but now i want to create auto login page on which admin can select user than login will be change by that user.

for i.e if admin is login currently.
now he click on user1 than it's old session(admin) mustbe invalidate and loged in as a user1. like switch user but no need to enter username and password again.

but i have to perform using j_security_check.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

j_security_check is standard POST with j_username and j_password as parameters; so you can perform a POST to the login page.

But that means you will have to bring back all the usernames and passwords to the UI to perform your this post.

Are you sure you want to do that? I would do this on the server side where, when the user is admin, you perform programmatic login based on a single username.

Comment: Yes, i want admin can login directly by the user name.